# Conditionally move row from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to move a row from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` if a certain value in `Sheet1` is `true`. For example:

If B12=8/12/2012 in `Sheet1`, then copy row 12 from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` by adding a new row under row 15 (which would be a named range) and then deleting the original row 12 from `Sheet1`.

Is this possible?

Comment: could you clarify *by adding a new row under row 15 (which would be a named range)* please ? did you mean under last row ? (PS : I know this is an old post and that the author probably won't see the comment... always worth trying :-)

Comment: Row 15 wouldn't necessarily be the last row. Is that the only way to do it? This is an old thread but I'm still curious as to what's the best way to do it. Thanks

Comment: *Is that the only way to do it?* no of course... should it be row15 in every case ?

Comment: No, it would just append the document after that.

Answer (score 1):

Hope This will work out...

```
function copyRowtoDiffSheet(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

 var cell = sheet1.getRange("B12").getCell(1, 1);//Get the B12 cell from sheet1
 var rowtoInsert = "15"; //Enter in which row you want to insert in sheet2

 if(cell.getValue() == "compareString") //compare cell.getValue() =="8/12/2012" 
 {

  sheet2.insertRows(rowtoInsert); //Insert a empty row in sheet2 at R15, It will be doing insert before operation. Successive rows will be moved below.
  var range2 = sheet2.getRange(rowtoInsert ,1,1,sheet1.getLastColumn()); // Select sheet2 row15 as a range
  sheet1.getRange(cell.getRow(),1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).copyTo(range2); // copy the selected sheet1 range into sheet2 range
  sheet1.deleteRow(cell.getRow()); //delete the R15 in sheet1
 }
}
```